# I missed the flying f*** out of you. Meaning

Tags: meaning, emphasis, offensive-language

Please explain me why FF uses here as meaning of missing?

Comment: The F-word can be used to intensify any f**ing thing. There doesn't have to be a reason. For details on its usage, see an educational video called 'The Wolf of Wall Street'.

Comment: Personally, I would probably be insulted is someone said that to me. *Flying f***" is usually used negatively, most commonly, "I don't give a --". "I missed the FF out of you" sounds like they didn't miss me much at all, or at any rate, missed me impolitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with a feeling or emotion, "out of you" is a slang expression meaning that the person addressed is responsible for that feeling.  Consider the Cole Porter song "I Get a Kick Out of You."  "Kick" means a jolt of enjoyment, so the title means roughly "I enjoy your company."

"Flying fuck" is a vulgar way to signal intensity, so "I don't give a fuck" means I don't care, and "I don't give a flying fuck" means I *really* don't care.

So you could say, "I really missed you," that is, "I had a really intense feeling of absence when you were gone."  Which is to say "I missed the flying fuck out of you."

The FF part isn't tied to just the word "missing."

Answer (score 4):

To me, this is an odd usage of FF.  Typically, "I don't give a flying fuck" is used to signal that one does not care one way or another, and doesn't want to be  bothered. One does not "give a damn".

**I don't give a flying fuck about some punctuation conventions, though others I consider very important.**

Or one can say:

**Go take a flying fuck on a rolling donut!**

and mean thereby that one has little patience and much contempt for the other person's actions or attitude.

Comment: I quite agree it's an "odd" usage. Personally, I'd be inclined to say the speaker isn't very articulate (as opposed to saying he's using a non-standard form skillfully, creatively, or amusingly). I'd need to see more text from the same person to be sure, but I'd be a bit surprised if my initial reaction was incorrect. Glossing over ***flying*** as a general-purpose "intensifier" (presumably, only for the specific noun ***fuck*** in this type of context) just looks like ignorance to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuck) says,

> ... and is also commonly used ... as an [intensifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier).

So "I missed you intensely" or "I missed you a lot".